# Is there a way I can ignore certain characters when reading a csv file in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting the following error when reading a csv file into a pandas dataframe: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 2360, saw 8

When I looked at the contents of the csv file I saw the following characters (backslash followed by quotation mark) in one of the fields at row 2360 which seems to be causing the issue: \"

I removed these characters manually from the csv file and my script worked fine.

Is there a way I can ignore these characters (namely \") upon reading the csv and without having to manually remove it from the file?

Comment: The characters are backslash followed by quotation '\"' .. the backslash does not appear in the body of the question.

Comment: Is that quote supposed to be part of a field or a quote that encloses a field? Can you give an example? In general its hard to answer questions like "can I just ignore a character" because that can depend on the data - it might break in other ways to just brute force ignore characters in a csv file - well, I mean especially for characters that can be part of the structure of the fields in the file (like commas - and in some cases double quotes).

Comment: These characters appear in some of the values within the csv (there is a column called 'Description' in the table within the csv file and the description value of the 2360th row contains these characters \"). Did that answer your question?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem - seems to be okay.  See here: [github gist](https://gist.github.com/northernocean/c244d33e0afc898b75f8e814d4b94d1b) Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?